# Make the hover stay on the elements that appears from it

Tags: html, css

I have item contains a title and content. When the title is hover upon, the content appear (like the example below).

The problem is that when cursor is moved from the card-title to the card-content, the div will disappears and flex animation will be close.

When cursor is move from the card-title to the card-content, the div and flex animation should stay.
How can this be achieved?

```
.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #7FB77E;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: .4em;
}

.card p {
  height: 100%%;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .5s;
  background: #7FB77E;
  border: 2px solid #42032C;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card p:hover {
  flex: 6;
}

.card p span {
  min-width: 14em;
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: all .5s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #42032C;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}

.card-content-1 {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 650px;
  position: absolute;
}

.card-content-2 {
  margin-top:80px;
  margin-left: 850px;
  position: absolute;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 9999s, opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.card p:hover + div.hidden {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.button {
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <p>
            <span class="card-title">GEEKS 1</span>
        </p>
    <div class="card-content-1 hidden">
      <h3>Title GEEKS 1</h3>
      <span>
        Description here and long long long.<br/>
        Description here and long long long.<br/>
      </span>
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <button class="button">Geeks 1 Btn 1</button>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <button class="button">Geeks 1 Btn 2</button>
        </ul>
        <ul> 
          <button class="button">Geeks 1 Btn 3</button>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    
        <p>
            <span class="card-title">GEEKS 2</span>
        </p>
    <div class="card-content-2 hidden">
      <h3>Title GEEKS 2</h3>
      <span>
        Description here and long long long.<br/>
        Description here and long long long.<br/>
        Description here and long long long.
      </span>
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <button class="button">GEEKS 2 Btn 1</button>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <button class="button">GEEKS 2 Btn 2</button>
        </ul>
        <ul> 
          <button class="button">GEEKS 2 Btn 3</button>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    
  

</body>

</html>
```

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #7FB77E;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: .4em;
}

.card p {
  height: 100%%;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .5s;
  background: #7FB77E;
  border: 2px solid #42032C;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card p:hover {
  flex: 6;
}

.card p span {
  min-width: 14em;
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: all .5s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #42032C;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}

.card-content-1 {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 650px;
  position: absolute;
}

.card-content-2 {
  margin-top:80px;
  margin-left: 850px;
  position: absolute;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 9999s, opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.card p:hover + div.hidden {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.button {
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <p>
            <span class="card-title">GEEKS 1</span>
        </p>
    <div class="card-content-1 hidden">
      <h3>Title GEEKS 1</h3>
      <span>
        Description here and long long long.<br/>
        Description here and long long long.<br/>
      </span>
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <button class="button">Geeks 1 Btn 1</button>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <button class="button">Geeks 1 Btn 2</button>
        </ul>
        <ul> 
          <button class="button">Geeks 1 Btn 3</button>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    
        <p>
            <span class="card-title">GEEKS 2</span>
        </p>
    <div class="card-content-2 hidden">
      <h3>Title GEEKS 2</h3>
      <span>
        Description here and long long long.<br/>
        Description here and long long long.<br/>
        Description here and long long long.
      </span>
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <button class="button">GEEKS 2 Btn 1</button>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <button class="button">GEEKS 2 Btn 2</button>
        </ul>
        <ul> 
          <button class="button">GEEKS 2 Btn 3</button>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    
  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please correct your HTML. The card div is not closed and you may not have a button as a direct child of a ul. [I assume you have control of thhe HTML? If so you could structure it so that it's not just one card?].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need javascript for that. The easiest way to do it is using the js library [jquery](https://jquery.com/).

First create a class for flex change,

```
.card_flex_6{
   flex: 6
}
```

Then call jquery cdn,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And write a jquery script,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".card").hover(function(){
    $(".card").removeClass('card_flex_6') //Remove flex class from other cards
    $(this).addClass('card_flex_6')
  });
});
</script>
```

Let me know if any error appears